# How to output float value in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout

I'm trying to make a program that uses the Taylor Sequence to approximate `e`.
However, I've come across a problem that makes me feel quite noobish at C++. the variable `e` is a float, but whenever I use `cout << e << "\n";` it just outputs 2, not 2.0 or 2.7 or whatever it should be outputting at any point in the code. Here's the `main()` code:

```
int main() {
    float e = 1.0;
    int d = 1;
    int counter = 25;
    while(counter>=1){
        counter-=1;
        e+=(1/fact(d));
        d++;
        cout << e << "\n";
    }
}
```

`fact()` computes the factorial (!) of a number. When I run the program I get 25 lines that say `2`. What am I doing wrong? And I do have `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` before the functions.

Comment: Assuming that `fact` returns an integer, change `1/fact(d)` to `1.0/fact(d)`.

Comment: If you think you're having trouble outputting floats, try `float x = 2.7; std::cout << x << '\n';`.

Comment: @barakmanos thank you. It worked. I had just been assuming that `int / int` should output float. Making it `1.0` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your division returns an integer and not actually a float. One of the sides of the division has to be a float for the output to be a float.

Changing:

```
e+=(1/fact(d));
```

to:

```
e += (1.0 / fact(d));
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: How about some credit to the comment which has stated the exact same reasoning two hours before you posted this answer?